# How to integrate Facebook the new Graph Api with Authlogic in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, authlogic, facebook-graph-api

**Edit**: What I recommend now with any Ruby application to use `omniauth` gem to get `access_token`, etc. and to use `koala` gem for Facebook Graph API.

I've began with a new project using Authlogic system for Authorization.

And I'm now wondering how could I connect Facebook oAuth sessions with my Authlogic session!

First of all I want to use and Authlogic-oAuth Gems/Plugins, I what I want to use are just

- http://github.com/intridea/oauth2
- and the interesting http://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph
- and associate them all with Authlogic.

I tried using Authlogic with authlogic-connect extension, but It didnt fill up my needs. And I think the three of the amazing gems above togother will make things done in quality and as I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we just need authlogic_oauth2 to handle this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just released a gem yesterday that adds OAuth2 support to Authlogic. You can find it here: http://github.com/andyhite/authlogic_oauth2

Comment: what about post/delete methods? I want to connect 'fbgraph' gem with authlogic_oauth2

Answer (score 1):

I used koala for the FB graph api and bridged that with authlogic with a bit of a rapidly thrown together gem authlogic_facebook_koala it's rough and ready but it bridges the gap between login via the JS SDK and authlogic.

Comment: Yes. currently I use Koala with omniauth!

Comment: I've replaced the above gem with [authlogic_facebook_shim](http://github.com/james2m/authlogic_facebook_shim) as it can now be extended to use other libraries than just koala.

Answer (score 0):

any clues if you can use the Javascript SDK?
it seems that Facebooker is no longer needed